Need help connecting my gaming monitor to my laptop while maintaining 144Hz
I have an Asus VG248QE monitor from 2013 and it does not support 144Hz when connected via HDMI, but I can only connect it to my laptop via HDMI because my laptop does not have a DisplayPort.
How do I connect it, use what, and still have 144Hz. It also says on the net that it can maintain 144Hz when connected via DisplayPort or DVI.

If it only supports 144Hz over DisplayPort and you cannot connect to it using DisplayPort then it seems that you are at an impass. Many of these monitors support 120Hz over HDMI instead.

@Mokubai Not this one because it has HDMI 1.4. According to Acer it can do 30~83 KHz (H) / 50~76 Hz (V) with the HDMI and up to 144Hz with the other connections (and DVI can do it because it's dual-link DVI-D).

If the laptop supports newer versions of HDMI, then you can get an HDMI to Displayport converter that supports 144@1080p. HDMI to DP is the more complicated direction and requires a more expensive active (powered) adapter, but it can work fine

Echoing others: Your only option is to do the research to find a hardware adapter that converts from your laptop's 144Hz-supporting HDMI connector to your monitor's 144Hz-supporting DisplayPort connector.
